# SQL query showing 2 different results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been practicing SQL query on [W3schools](http://goo.gl/pL6rcn). I'm practicing LIKE in WHERE clause. The following query is working on the site but not working on the SQL SERVER 2008 R2 which is installed on my machine.

```
 SELECT * FROM Customers
 WHERE CustomerName LIKE '[!uvwxyz]%';
```

This will result into Customer Names starting other then UVWXYZ. When I fire the same query into local machine, the syntax " [! ] " is not seems to be working. Customer name starting with UVWXYZ are also resulted into result.

What mistake I am doing?

Comment: First of. do not use W3schools for learning. Next, MySQL !=MS SQL Server - and so if something is working in sql server, there's no guarantee it will work in MySQL.

Comment: Okay, but what SQL query must work when fired that should result the same? And W3schools isn't good for beginners you meant to say?

Comment: W3schoold isn't good - that I want to say. And if your DBMS are different in different places - then if something is not working - that should not surprise you

Comment: @AlmaDo  Okay. But I find easy on W3schools as I'm beginner. Any other resources you'd like to share then you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

In `SQL-SERVER`, to list all customer whose names don't start with `[uvwxyz]`

```
 SELECT * FROM Customers
 WHERE CustomerName NOT LIKE '[u-z]%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query instead.

This will list out all the records with `CustomerName` not starting with `UVWXYZ`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerName NOT LIKE 'uvwxyz%';
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is same as Vijay has shared.

Answer (score 0):

> Please Try This

```
SELECT * FROM ##TBL_TEMP
 WHERE NAME not  LIKE '[u-z]%';
```

> all customer whose names start except [uvwxyz]

Comment: Thank you, but it is same as Vijay has shared. Please don't re-post the same answer.